# Kelvin-Helmholtz theorem in Relativistic regime

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, magnetohydrodynamics, relativistic-jets

Using the Carter-Lichnerowicz equation of motion $\Omega_{\mu \nu}u^{\nu}=T\nabla_{\mu}s$, we obtain $Tu^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}s=0$, where s is the specific entropy, $u^{\mu}$ the velocity of the fluid and $\Omega_{\mu \nu}=2\nabla_{[\nu}w_{\mu ]}$ is the vorticity tensor of the fluid ($w^{\mu}=hu^{\mu}$ with $h$ the specific entalpy).

In the proof of the Kelvin-helmholtz theorem after having proved $\nabla_{\alpha}(u^{\alpha}\Omega^{\beta}\nabla_{\beta}s)=0$, let us consider the comoving frame $x^{\mu}=(t,s,a,b)$ with $u^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}a=0=u^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}b$ and $u^{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\rho}\epsilon^{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}\nabla_{\beta}s\nabla_{\mu}b\nabla_{\nu}a$.

Here my problems:

1. by construction the fluid will be spatially bounded (in what sense)?
2. next we consider a flow in which two-dimensional surfaces with constant specific entropy s at a fixed time cut through the fluid and are cylinder-like; each of such surfaces will produce a tube as it evolves in time and thus a cylinder in the (t, s) subspace; now let $l(s)$ be one of the curves where one such (t, s)-tube intersects the boundary of the fluid and $\Gamma(s)$ any closed curve around the same (t,s)-cylinders; denoting then with $\sigma$ thesurface between $l(s)$ and $\Gamma(s)$, we can write the relativistic circulation $\mathcal{C}$ as $\mathcal{C}=\oint_{\Gamma}hu_{\mu}dx^{\mu}=\oint_{l}hu_{\mu}dx^{\mu} + \oint_{\sigma}\Omega_{\mu \nu}dx^{[\mu}dx^{\nu]}$
   So I can not see this point( is my picture correct? of course a,b,t are changing in the comoving frame…)
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: solved thanks bye